# Jquery Ajax Post refuses to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

When attempting to use the JQuery Ajax post function, I have exhausted all the options I could think of for it to work. I just need to post the data to a PHP handler and pass 2 variables. I confirmed the function is being called fine when I comment out the post code (alert is called), but as soon as I uncomment the line, nothing happens. I am using Firefox but have also tried it with Chrome as well.

```
<script type="text/javarscript">
    function removeDatacenter( datacenter_id ) {    
        alert( datacenter_id );
        $.ajax({ 
           type: "POST", 
           url: "handler.php", 
           data: { action-type: 'remove_datacenter', id: '2' }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: specify the FULL path in the "url" parameter

Comment: @Th0rndike Where did you get the idea it only accepts absolute paths?

Comment: I've had trouble when specifying relative paths. What does your handler look like, anyway?

Comment: Well, it does accept relative paths.  Perhaps you are experiencing some bugs, but it does.  Always read [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open()-method) to be sure.

Comment: sorry edited your post by mistake

Comment: you should check your browsers' error console if your javascript is not working... it should have mentioned an error and the relevant line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap action-type key object inside quotes because of '-' character:

*You could rename it to ,e.g, actionType*

```
$.ajax({ 
 type: "POST", 
 url: "handler.php", 
 data: { 'action-type': 'remove_datacenter', id: datacenter_id } 
})
```

Comment: Why only action-type and not "id" as well? Just out of curiosity of course, trying it now.

Comment: @BrettPowell no need to wrap `id`. You have to wrap key name when using special character as '-'

Comment: action-type (without quotes) will try to evaluate the expression action minus type. But this will fail. There should be an exception in your Javascript console, though.

Comment: `$.ajax().done(function(data){/*use data here*/});` You have to return something from your php script of course and then you can use 'data'. Here your ajax method will wait for data type text/html (default), if you want to get data in other format, you can specify it using ajax option dataType or use more specific ajax method as $.getJSON() e.g

Comment: Thanks, was confused a bit. I have the .done(function(result)) and the alert box shows but all paths return a value in the handler (just dummy stuff like "YES", "NO") but the alert box shows an empty value when printing result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "handler.php", 
    data: { 
        'action-type': 'remove_datacenter', 
        id: 2
    } 
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between your and roasted's answer?